# Can Django send multi-part responses for a single request?

Tags: python, django, api, rest, response

I apologise if this is a daft question. I'm currently writing against a Django API (which I also maintain) and wish under certain circumstances to be able to generate multiple partial responses in the case where a single request yields a large number of objects, rather than sending the entire JSON structure as a single response.

Is there a technique to do this? It needs to follow a standard such that client systems using different request libraries would be able to make use of the functionality.

The issue is that the client system, at the point of asking, does not know the number of objects that will be present in the response.

If this is not possible, then I will have to chain requests on the client end - for example, getting the first 20 objects & if the response suggests there will be more, requesting the next 20 etc. This approach is an OK work-around, but any subsequent requests rely on the previous response. I'd rather ask once and have some kind of multi-part response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, No you can't send `Multipart http response` not yet atleast. `Multipart` response is only valid in http requests. Why? Because no browser as I know of completely supports this.

1. **Firefox 3.5**: Renders only the last part, others are ignored.
2. **IE 8**: Shows all the content as if it were text/plain, including the    boundaries.
3. **Chrome 3**: Saves all the content in a single file, nothing is rendered.
4. **Safari 4**: Saves all the content in a single file, nothing is rendered.
5. **Opera 10.10**: Something weird. Starts rendering the first part as plain/text, and then clears everything. The loading progress bar hangs on 31%.

(Data credits Diego Jancic)

Comment: My request method is not limited to a GET request. If I had an endpoint that accepted a POST request, could it be done?

Comment: You can always send multipart in request, but browsers don't accept it in response